# Cannot display opencv Detections on PyQt ui

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I can show my webcam Video on PyQt ui but when I perform detections using open cv dnn module it is not being displayed on the ui
Can anyone help me and show me the way to display detections on the ui

For example when I use the part of detections below

```
classes, scores, boxes = model.detect(frame, CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD, NMS_THRESHOLD)

        for (classid, score, box) in zip(classes, scores, boxes):
            color = COLORS[int(classid) % len(COLORS)]
            label = "%s : %f" % (class_names[classid], score)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, box, color, 2)
            cv2.putText(frame, label, (box[0], box[1] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, color, 2)
```

Then I simply get this output for few seconds and it closes automatically [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4GRn.png)

I want the empty frame to have webcame running with detection like it does when i use cv.imshow() function

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of your attempt.

Comment: @musicamante see i have made some changes

Comment: Sorry but that is not what I asked. We need a code that we can easily copy, paste and run, possibly without any substantial modification.